# Spaces allowed in Schemas for DD4T?

Tags: dd4t, schema

I typically suggest business-friendly Schemas names (Component definitions). My current customer explained their Schemas don't have spaces because of DD4T (Java).

- What causes this in DD4T?
- What characters are allowed for DD4T schemas?

<strike>Also, is this a strict requirement--can they somehow allow spaces in Tridion Schemas?</strike>

**Update**: based on Rogier's answer, my premise was wrong. Let me ask instead, **how are Schema names used in DD4T** (Java, if there's a different)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no requirement whatsoever in DD4T java to not allow spaces in schema names. I run many DD4T java projects and all of them have many schemas with spaces in the names.

Comment: Ok, so this is likely implementation-specific. I'll change my question to ask how is the Schema name used in DD4T?

Comment: It isn't specifically - its just a String that's exposed in content delivery to be used when you need it. There really is no difference between dd4t and regular tridion here.